# How to send email reports at large scale for every 12 AM using azure webjob?

Tags: c#, timezone, azure-webjobs

I have an Azure web job that is running continuously and will send report emails at 12 AM when a user's timezone time reaches 12 AM. It is expected that these reports will send at 12 AM. Consider the system has 100 users and 50 of them are in the same timezone. it is expected that these 50 users should get their mail at 12 AM. But what happening is that all are getting at the different time. The starting time is at 12 AM.

Here is my logic

```
foreach(var item in reports){
    if(Convert.ToDateTime(item.LastSendDate).Date < UserTimezoneDate.Date){
                // send mail logic using report id
    }
}
```

Someone suggestdd that use multithreading, it is a possible solution, but I want to implement it a large scale basis. So if I use multithreading is it a good approach? Is it good to use service fabric? If yes how can implement it(logic only)?

Comment: What is the data type of `item.LastSendDate`? Are you using `DateTimeOffset`?

Comment: How long does each report take to be generated?  How long does this entire process take?

Comment: @gunr2171 it is in string format.

Comment: @Jason Geiger I didn't know the generation time. It is running in azure and I haven't access to the logs.

Comment: How are you determining the user's time zone? How are you handling that in your application?

Comment: Actually, these are handling in my code successfully. That is not a problem. There is always some delay in mail logic. But it is acceptable.